# Code signing issue with xcdatamodeld included in podspec

Tags: ios, xcode6, cocoapods, codesign

I am trying to include a Core Data .xcdatamodeld file in a Cocoapods Podspec. This file is within my Assets directory and is included in the Podspec as follows:

```
s.resources = 'Assets/**/*'
```

This works fine when running the app in the simulator, but when I try to run the app on a physical device, I get this error:

```
unsealed contents present in the bundle root 
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

If I add the .xcdatamodeld file to my project through Xcode without adding it to my Podspec, the code signing phase completes successfully and the app runs as expected. This is not an ideal solution however. I would prefer to add it to the Podspec to avoid the extra step of having to manually add the .xcdatamodeld file to all of the projects that use that Podspec.

I started seeing this error after I upgraded to Xcode 6 and OSX 10.9.5. Are there any parameters I can set in my Podspec to get my .xcdatamodeld file to be code signed successfully? Could this possibly be a bug in Cocoapods due to the recent updates to Xcode and OSX?

Using cocoapods-0.33.1

Comment: Still an issue as of Cocoapods 0.34.4.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good idea to add the resources to a bundle just like this:

```
s.ios.resource_bundle = { 'Assets' => ['YourCoreData.xcdatamodeld'] }
```

This way, instead of copying the resources into the root, they are bundled together in a resource bundle.
See http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#tab_resource_bundles

Answer (score 0):

I integrated Core Data with the following pod spec lines:

`s.resources =     'Pod/CoreData/coredata.xcdatamodeld'
  s.preserve_paths = 'Pod/CoreData/coredata.xcdatamodeld'`

that + erasing derived data fixed this issue for me (using cocoa pods 0.36 )